# Vertically align div to middle of element

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So basically, I want my page to look like this. The logo (green triangle) is "images/logo.png", and the three other boxes are Username input/Password input/Submit button.

[image]

The code I have tried does not work - it squashes it all up on the left side of the page.

```
 <div class="login-box">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <img src="{{ asset('images/logo.png') }}" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <p align="center">{{ form_widget(form.username, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'authentication.username'|trans } }) }}</p>
                    <p align="center">{{ form_widget(form.password, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'authentication.password'|trans } }) }}</p>
                    <p align="center">{{ form_widget(form.log_in, {'attr': {'class': 'btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block'}, 'label': 'authentication.log.in'|trans }) }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<style>
    .login-box {
        width: 800px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
</style>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume your parent `element` is 100% `height` and `width` of the viewport.

You can easily vertically align any element, if you don't mind using the `transform` property, with a few lines of code.

```
.class {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

You can throw in a `margin: 0 auto;` if you want to horizontally align it as well (and it is a block type element).

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/nyjovxcj/)

To apply it to your code:

- Make sure the parent of `login-box` is the element with `100%` `height` and `width`.
- Apply the above styles to the `login-box` class.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [example demo](http://www.bootply.com/ezmCcAShER) with some dummy data but you will get the idea how to achieve it

```
.col-sm-2, .col-sm-10 {
min-height: 100vh;
display: flex;
align-items : center;
}
```

Comment: That does vertically align it, but it's still all squashed up and left centred. See this image: http://postimg.org/image/r4fqdajfr/ - thanks for your help I appreciate it :)

Comment: @b85411 i did not had access to the images you used so thats only i could do for you from your code. Create a jsfiddle with your image and input fields and i can help you more on that

Comment: It's just a 144x144 png

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using the col-sm-offset to change the position of your image and your fields.  Try:

```
<div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-4">
     <img src="{{ asset('images/logo.png') }}" />
</div>
<div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-6">
```

Play with "col-sm-offset-x" until you get it positioned correctly.

Comment: i thought of that but i am not sure how can it help him to align it vertically center?