# Center div element in an overlay over the parent div with css?

Tags: html, css, overlay

I'm using a div overlay over a parent div, and would like to center another div right in the middle of the overlay. This is as close as I've come:

```css
.parent { 
        width: 400px; 
}

#aoa55a92 { 
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8); 
}

.aoa_wrap {
        position: relative;
        z-index:999;
}

.aoa_overlay {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        z-index:9999;
        color:#fff;
        overflow:hidden;
}

.aoa_object {
        display: inline-block;
        width:100%;
        text-align:center;
        vertical-align:middle;
        overflow:hidden;
        margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<html><body>


<div class='parent'>

<div class="aoa_wrap">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    <div id="aoa55a92" class="aoa_overlay">
        <div class="aoa_object">I want this in center</div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: [This was a recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404950/vertically-align-div-to-middle-of-element/33405293#33405293) that was quite similar - [Vertically align div to middle of element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404950/vertically-align-div-to-middle-of-element/33405293#33405293)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply adding:

```
position: relative;
top: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

to your `.aoa_object` class will center it vertically.

```css
.parent { 
        width: 400px; 
}

#aoa55a92 { 
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8); 
}

.aoa_wrap {
        position: relative;
        z-index:999;
}

.aoa_overlay {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        z-index:9999;
        color:#fff;
        overflow:hidden;
}

.aoa_object {
        display: inline-block;
        width:100%;
        text-align:center;
        vertical-align:middle;
        overflow:hidden;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
        top: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
        transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>

<div class="aoa_wrap">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    <div id="aoa55a92" class="aoa_overlay">
        <div class="aoa_object">I want this in center</div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Never used transform before. Worked great. :)

Comment: @johnh10 glad it helped!

Comment: awesome. It helped mine css problem. Can you please explain how transform and top works together?

Comment: @MA1 I'll give some brief insight. The `top` value moves the element to the center of the page (vertically) but it doesn't account for the actual height of the element (so the item is centered `+` half the height). The `transform` value "moves" the element upwards by `50%` of it's height (same thing as taking half the actual height value and applying a negative `margin-top`). From here you should do some self research and maybe even share your finding with the rest of us.