# Caption in Safari is not centered vertically

Tags: css, safari

So this issue has been bugging me for quite a while. I have this div container that centers an overflow image to the center.

However in Safari, the icon inside the div is not positioned in the center. Instead it is at the top. It works fine in other browsers though. Only Safari has this bug.

I attached a fiddle below. Appreciate any help! :)

[**JSfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2stywe2t/1/)

```js
var $container = $('#page');
$container.masonry({
  columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
  itemSelector: '.item',
  percentPosition: true,
  gutter: 10
});
```

```css
#page .item {
  width: calc(16.66% - 10px);
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0;
  float: left;
  padding-bottom: 16.66%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: salmon;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
}
#page .item.s1 {
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: navy;
}
.item > a {
  /* position: relative; */
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
}
.item:hover .grid-image:after {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}
.item:hover .grid-image > img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
.item:hover .item-caption {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 3;
  visibility: visible;
}
.item-caption,
.grid-image > img,
.grid-image:after {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.item-caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(29, 106, 154, 0.72);
  color: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.item-caption > div {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.grid-image {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.grid-image img {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.grid-image:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.3.2/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div id="page">

    <!-- GRID ITEM -->
    <div class="item s1">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="grid-image">
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4e/Pleiades_large.jpg/1024px-Pleiades_large.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="item-caption">
          <div>
            <h5>I want this to be center</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- /GRID ITEM -->

  </div>
</div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can I suggest another approach?

Comment: You can use use absolute positioning and transform. Look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33664202/vertically-center-content-that-exceeds-window-height/33664285#33664285 
Let me know if that is what you look for!